Expo environment variables for updates not being picked up
I am currently struggling to understand how to correctly define ENV var based on context.
Here is my example eas.json
    {
      "build": {
        "development": {
          "developmentClient": true,
          "distribution": "internal",
          "channel": "development",
          "env": {
            "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "http://localhost:3000"
          }
        },
        "preview": {
          "distribution": "internal",
          "channel": "staging",
          "env": {
            "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "https://staging.domain"
          }
        },
        "production": {
          "channel": "main",
          "env": {
            "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "https://prod.domain"
          }
        }
      }
    }

I also have an .env.local, referencing it (as i assume, eas.json won't get picked on laptop dev):
    #DO NOT COMMIT THIS
    SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN=xxxx
    EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:3000

When running update

eas update --branch staging --message "feat(onboarding): navigation"

No matter what, env.local takes over.
What should be fixed to have it correctly working ?
I want eas.json preview.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL to be picked up

Simply change you ENV variables value in your .env.local file from

http://localhost:3000

to

https://staging.domain

Your flow and eas.json file is correct but is purely for building. For example, when you want a preview build, it will use those predefined ENV variables. But to test locally, you will need to change your .env.local file.
Be sure to restart your development server!
Edit:
These predefined env variables are for building

eas build --profile [development | preview | production] --platform [android | ios]


I might be an expo noob, but i was destructuring outside of components : const { EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL, etc... } = process.env;. bad. // process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL within the component works.
100% unexpectable

I use a library called dotenv to manage my environment variables. Maybe this can also help you.

as they're saying, "read the doc" !! my bad on that one
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/#how-to-read-from-environment-variables

Is there a way I could set env variable that only applies to eas update on PR branch?
I wonder where I should set the variable and keep it

I suggest following the documentation because I personally have no experience with this - https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/environment-variables/
